# How can I use the find command to remove directories without eliminating certain subdirectories?

Tags: linux, unix, find

I am trying to modify the following command in a script that removes directories based on age.

Example directories would be the following:

```
/a/b/c/2011/11/11
/a/b/c/2011/11/11/12-ACD-1234
/a/b/c/2011/11/14
```

The current inaccurate attempt is the following:

```
find /a/b -type d -mindepth 2 -depth ! -name '*ACD*' -mtime +180 -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Although this script will not remove directories containing "ACD", the parent directory will be removed. I have tried -prune combinations and other tricks but am unable to get the desired result.

Is there a way to hone this find command to preserve subdirectories matching certain criteria? In this example, the parent directories /a/b/c/2011 and /a/b/c/2011/11 would have to be preserved as to not recursively remove the subdirectory.

I am looking to do this with just a find command, if at all possible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The chief issue is that find gives you a lovely list of directories as output, but you need a way to evaluate each of those on their own to determine whether they have an `*ACD*` somewhere in a subdirectory.  And piped commands don't seem to work well (or at all?) as an argument to find's `-exec`.

So one approach would be to create your own command script that `-exec` can call, which will return 0 if its argument contains no subdirectory `*ACD*`, and 1 otherwise.  This seems to work for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
# script: /path/to/hasnoACD
list=`find $1 -name '*ACD*'`
[ "x$list" = "x" ] && exit 0 || exit 1
```

Then your desired find command just uses `-exec` twice:

```
find /a/b -type d -mindepth 2 -depth ! -name '*ACD*' -mtime +180 -exec /path/to/hasnoACD {} \;  -exec rm -rf {} +
```

`-exec /path/to/hasnoACD {} \;` will evaluate as true only for the cases you want.

Another alternative: I initially approached this in a way similar to @icyrock-com, in that I ended up with a find command piped to a while loop, which handles the directory removals.  The 'while' syntax will depend on your shell, and you'll need a way to distinguish directories that contain some `*ACD*` subdirectory as we did above with the `hasnoACD` script, but in bash on FreeBSD the following seems to work:

```
find /a/b -type d -mindepth 2 -depth ! -name '*ACD*' -mtime +180 | while read mydir ; do find $mydir -name '*ACD*' | xargs false && rm -rf $mydir ; done
```

Note the find within the while loop -- only when that find returns nothing (no `*ACD*` subdirs) will xargs return true, so that the `rm -rf $mydir` is executed.  This behavior of xargs works on my FreeBSD machine, but on Linux or Solaris the behavior is different, so some other test would be needed.

As @icyrock-com suggests, you may wish to do a `mv` rather than a `rm`, just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks. The 1st solution you gave works great. The 2nd solution (while loop) does not work. Piping to `xargs false` always returns false.

Comment: Interesting.  On my FreeBSD box, piping an empty result to `xargs false` returns true -- but this doesn't work on CentOS or Solaris.  I'll edit my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this with `find` only, but here's a test script you can try - try this in /tmp or somewhere safe:

```
# Prepare
rm -rf a
mkdir -p a/b/c
for a in c d; do
  for i in 2010 2011; do
    for j in 05 11; do
      mkdir -p a/b/$a/$i/$j/will-delete
      if [ $j != 05 ]; then
        mkdir -p a/b/$a/$i/$j/will-ACD-leave
      fi
    done
  done
done
echo Created

# List
echo ----- Listing
find a

# Remove
echo ----- Removing
find a/b -depth -type d ! -name "*ACD*"|while read l; do
  num_entries=`ls -a "$l"|wc -l`
  if [ $num_entries -eq 2 ]; then
    echo Removing $l
    rm -rf "$l"
  fi
done

# List
echo ----- Listing
find a
```

Note the above removes the `-mtime +180` for testing, so you need to adjust as needed. The output would be this:

```
Created
----- Listing
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/2010
a/b/c/2010/05
a/b/c/2010/05/will-delete
a/b/c/2010/11
a/b/c/2010/11/will-delete
a/b/c/2010/11/will-ACD-leave
a/b/c/2011
a/b/c/2011/05
a/b/c/2011/05/will-delete
a/b/c/2011/11
a/b/c/2011/11/will-delete
a/b/c/2011/11/will-ACD-leave
a/b/d
a/b/d/2010
a/b/d/2010/05
a/b/d/2010/05/will-delete
a/b/d/2010/11
a/b/d/2010/11/will-delete
a/b/d/2010/11/will-ACD-leave
a/b/d/2011
a/b/d/2011/05
a/b/d/2011/05/will-delete
a/b/d/2011/11
a/b/d/2011/11/will-delete
a/b/d/2011/11/will-ACD-leave
----- Removing
Removing a/b/c/2010/05/will-delete
Removing a/b/c/2010/05
Removing a/b/c/2010/11/will-delete
Removing a/b/c/2011/05/will-delete
Removing a/b/c/2011/05
Removing a/b/c/2011/11/will-delete
Removing a/b/d/2010/05/will-delete
Removing a/b/d/2010/05
Removing a/b/d/2010/11/will-delete
Removing a/b/d/2011/05/will-delete
Removing a/b/d/2011/05
Removing a/b/d/2011/11/will-delete
----- Listing
a
a/b
a/b/c
a/b/c/2010
a/b/c/2010/11
a/b/c/2010/11/will-ACD-leave
a/b/c/2011
a/b/c/2011/11
a/b/c/2011/11/will-ACD-leave
a/b/d
a/b/d/2010
a/b/d/2010/11
a/b/d/2010/11/will-ACD-leave
a/b/d/2011
a/b/d/2011/11
a/b/d/2011/11/will-ACD-leave
```

The above will delete empty parent folders, so if that's the problem, you may want to modify the `while` loop to just make a dummy file after each `rm` and then do another top-level `find` to delete these (name them in some way for easier finding).

As a separate note - instead of delete, I suggest doing a `mv` somewhere instead until you are sure this is what you want. Backing up before is another option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, icyrock. This solution would work if the directories are empty. However, if there are files in those directories, then there would be more than two entries for an `ls -a`.